# How can i set unique mail registration in my Django project?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I was testing my registration view and i noticed that if i try to register using an alreaxy existing Username, i'll get an error; if i try to register using an already existing email, the app will let me do so.

Obviously, i don't want someone to register multiple accounts with the same email on my site. I'm fairly new to Django, and since i noticed that the form checked if an username already exists, i thought it would do the same with the email field.

I don't really know how to go from that, should i work on my view or on the form? And how can i make it loop through my DB and find if an e-mail had already been registered? I thought `email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')` would do the trick, but it didn't.
Any help is appreciated.

Here is my view:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            messages.success(request, f"New Account Created: {username}")
            login(request, user)
            messages.info(request, f"You are now logged in as {username}")
            return redirect("main:homepage")
        else:
            for msg in form.error_messages:
                messages.error(request, f"{msg}: {form.error_messages[msg]}")


    form = NewUserForm
    return render(request,
                  "main/register.html",
                  context={"form":form})
```

And here is the form:

```
class NewUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email", "password1", "password2")


    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(NewUserForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Answer (score 1):

Compare the email address provided with email address in User model .

```
if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
    if User.objects.filter(email__exact=email).count() == 0:
            messages.success(request, f"New Account Created: {username}")
            login(request, user)
            messages.info(request, f"You are now logged in as {username}")
            return redirect("main:homepage")
    else:
      return HttpResponse('This email address is already registered ')
```

Comment: Hey! I just tried it, unfortunately it does not seem to work. I'm trying to find where the error is!

Comment: please refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/ , hope it helps .

Answer (score 0):

I think the best alternative is to program your own user model, this will allow you to add a unique restriction on email, You can take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example)